# how to skip 2 data index array on numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

so I have an 8x6 array, then I want to make the array 4x6.the data such as below:

```
array([[76, 34, 56, 32, 55, 66],
       [99, 23, 11, 34, 45, 32],
       [87, 98, 87, 23, 12, 77],
       [78, 98, 89, 28, 91, 72],
       [76, 42, 45, 23, 56, 87],
       [81, 22, 34, 42, 81, 23],
       [91, 23, 45, 67, 45, 34],
       [87, 98, 23, 45, 23, 55]])
```

the data I want such below:

```
array([[87, 98, 87, 23, 12, 77],
       [78, 98, 89, 28, 91, 72],
       [91, 23, 45, 67, 45, 34],
       [87, 98, 23, 45, 23, 55]])
```

I've try use the slices but it doesn't work for my case. the code is here:

```
import numpy as np

data = [
    [76,34,56,32,55,66],
    [99,23,11,34,45,32],
    [87,98,87,23,12,77],
    [78,98,89,28,91,72],
    [76,42,45,23,56,87],
    [81,22,34,42,81,23],
    [91,23,45,67,45,34],
    [87,98,23,45,23,55]
]

data = np.array(data)
data[::2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
data[np.arange(len(data))%4>1]
```

Or for a generic method:

```
N = 2
data[np.arange(len(data))%(2*N) >= N]
```

Output:

```
array([[87, 98, 87, 23, 12, 77],
       [78, 98, 89, 28, 91, 72],
       [91, 23, 45, 67, 45, 34],
       [87, 98, 23, 45, 23, 55]])
```

Comment: how if I want skip 50 data

Comment: so the data will be (15000,6),then I want make the data (7500,6) I want skip every 50 data and still keep the 50 data after skipping. the concept is the same as above

Comment: I updated the method to be generic, in the second case use `N = 50`

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

data = [
    [76,34,56,32,55,66],
    [99,23,11,34,45,32],
    [87,98,87,23,12,77],
    [78,98,89,28,91,72],
    [76,42,45,23,56,87],
    [81,22,34,42,81,23],
    [91,23,45,67,45,34],
    [87,98,23,45,23,55]
]

data = np.array(data)
import itertools


def filter_mask(data, mask):
    return list(itertools.compress(data, itertools.cycle(mask)))

print(filter_mask(data, mask=[0, 0, 1, 1]))
```

Comment: how if I want skip 50 data? so the data will be (15000,6),then I want make the data (7500,6) I want skip every 50 data and still keep the 50 data after skipping. the concept is the same as above

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).